# HTTP Get request for XML from API

Tags: java, xml, api, get, http-headers

I'm particularly new to API calling in java to request for XML, so I'm using a template. It can be seen below.

However, now that I'm calling an API from another web API, they require me to use python which I'm clueless about, or use a [3rd party HTTP web client](http://requestmaker.com/). Instead, I want the calling of the API to be within my java application itself. Is it possible to alter the codes below with the following headers?

> Sample request URL: http:// datamall.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice.svc/TravelTimeSet
>
> Request headers: AccountKey=xxx, UniqueUserId=xxx, accept=application/atom+xml
>
> [API documentation/guide](http://www.mytransport.sg/content/dam/mytransport/DataMall_StaticData/LTA_DataMall_API_User_Guide.pdf)

**NowCast.java** *NowCast.java is linked to a SAX parser

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class NowCast extends SAXParser {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String datasetName, keyRef;
    datasetName = "Nowcast";
    keyRef = "781CF461BB6606ADEA6B1B4F3228DE9DB26ABF1B1B755E93";

    NowCast od = new NowCast();

    try {
        od.callWebAPI(datasetName, keyRef);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void callWebAPI(String datasetName, String keyRef) throws Exception {
    // Step 1: Construct URL
    String url = "http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI?dataset=" + datasetName
            + "&keyref=" + keyRef;

    // Step 2: Call API Url
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    // Step 3: Check the response status
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        // Step 3a: If response status == 200
        // print the received xml
        super.Parserr(con.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(readStream(con.getInputStream()));
    } else {
        // Step 3b: If response status != 200
        // print the error received from server
        System.out.println("Error in accessing API - "
                + readStream(con.getErrorStream()));
    }
}

// Read the responded result
private String readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    reader.close();
    return response.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross-referenced the python code (in the API documentation) with the code above and solved the problem

**Setting request headers in java**

> URL obj = new URL(url);
>
> HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
>
> con.setRequestMethod("GET");
>
> con.setRequestProperty("AccountKey", "zIIkxPOqBRxnkH97G6ZGlA==");
>
> con.setRequestProperty("UniqueUserID", "5ccef4a0-10e2-4f75-8f4d-2be67885b10f");
>
> con.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/atom+xml");